# RemoveView Function On ViewPager Not Working

Tags: android, image

> I'm trying to remove a view from a Container of type ViewGroup like below, and I cast it into a ViewPager, but I noticed that the removeView() function is not working, as at now, I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong.
>   I need help.

```
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)container;
            View view = (View)object;
            ViewPager.removeView(view); //removeView is not working


        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);


            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)container;
            ViewPager.addView(view);
            return view;
```

Comment: Your variable is `viewPager`, with a lowercase `v`. `ViewPager` with an uppercase `V` is the class. You cannot call `removeView()` or `addView()` on the class. Change it to `viewPager` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It is works as expected. Instead of doing above, you need to remove the item for the `ViewPager` adapter. Something like below.

```
// Delete a page at a `position`
public void deletePage(int position)  {
    // Remove the corresponding item in the data set 
    pageIndexes.remove(position);
    // Notify the adapter that the data set is changed
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```